# When are simple sorts faster than 'complex' sorts?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have been given a sorting algorithm assignment through school and our task is to review several sorting algorithms. One of the sections for the report is to do with "when are simple sorts faster".

The sorting algorithms i have are:

- Bubble sort
- Selection sort
- Insertion

which are all O(n^2) average

Then i have the following O(n log n) algorithms:

- Merge sort
- Quick sort

and Radix sort O(kn)

I have ran several tests on unsorted and sorted data ranging from n entries of 10 up to 100,000 and always the complex sorts O(n log n) execute in a faster time.

I also tried using sorted data sets containing n elements where n = 10 up to n = 100,000

But still the O(n log n) algorithms were faster.

SO my question is, when are the simple sorts faster than the complex ones.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Remember the C. For *small N*, a small C can result in a faster wall-clock time. This is why something like a quicksort implementation may use a bubblesort for the leaves. (If a bubblesort on n=10 is not faster, or at least equivalent, I would almost suspect the implementations - back when I did a similar research project for school n=20 was about the cutoff for bubble/quicksort, but it might also be compiler/CPU differences.)

Comment: Radix sort isn't O(n log n). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: Use real small inputs. Start n from 2.

Comment: How are you timing these?

Comment: @TimothyShields ye my mistake its O(nk) sorry

Comment: Show your code and your timing mechanism. Also be sure that you're timing release code and no debugger is attached. Without seeing your code, there's no way we can help you identify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branching within inner loops of the sorts that have run time proportional to the square of the input size tends to be very simple.

Insertion sort usually works out best of all in this regard.

On the other hand, sorts with run time proportional to N log N for input of size N have more complicated branching.

The branching complexity shows up as a constant factor in the run time.  So we have simple and complex run times of

```
S N^2  and  C N log N
```

On older computers, S tended to be quite a bit smaller than C.  Say just for fun you have  S = 1 and C = 4, then you have an equation that can be solved:

```
1 N^2 = 4 N log N
```

The solution of interest is at N = 16 (logs are base 2).  This is the size of input where the constant factor of better speed that the "simple" algorithm has is overcome by the better asymptotic speed.  Inputs smaller than 16 will be sorted faster by the sinple algorithm!  The power of the complex algorithm "kicks in" for N > 16.

HOWEVER, in modern computers - as you have discovered - faster branching at the hardware level and better compilers have made S and C much closer.   Only for tiny embedded processors is the old folklore about N^2 sorts running faster clearly observable in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the particular implementation of the algorithms. Typically, insertion sort will beat most of the O(n log n) sorts for n between 0 and low tens of elements, but the actual number depends on how insertion sort is implemented, how sorted the data is, how expensive comparisons are, etc. This is something where you pretty much have to run the particular implementations of the sorting algorithms against one another to determine which one is faster when.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would also add that it depends to some extent on the size of the data elements being sorted - for those algorithms that swap elements, a 32-bit integer element or a pointer element can be moved a lot quicker than a 64KB chunk of data (assuming the data has meaningful comparison operations - something like a huge integer implementation or something)...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, radix sort is not `O(nlogn)`. It is `O(kn)` where k is the maximum number of digits in any number.

`O(n^2)` sorts can be faster than `O(nlogn)` sorts when

1. Size of input is small. If your input contains ~100 (or even ~1000) numbers, modern processors can show `O(n^2)` sorts to be faster (or same as `O(nlogn)`).
2. For some cases an `O(n^2)` sort can stop in the middle of its sorting when it recognizes the array to be sorted which is difficult (but still possible) to implement in case of `O(nlogn)` sorts.

   For example, in Insertion sort or Flagged Bubble sort, it can be possible to stop the algorithm if the array becomes sorted. This results in best case `O(n)` performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is small or if the input is almost sorted then the "simple" sort algorithms work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

To get the answer for this one you will first understand how Big O works.

10000 n^2 is O(n^2)
10 n^3 is O(n^3)

so lets say n is 2

then 10 n^3 will work way faster than 10000 n^2.

but assuming you don't know the length of n or n can be really big then 10000 n^2 will be better

Answer (score 0):

> my question is, when are the simple sorts faster than the complex ones.

**It is hard to tell in general;** too much depends on the implementation details, on the data and on the hardware, etc.

However, I can give you one practical example. Quicksort has an O(n*log(n)) complexity, insertion sort O(n<sup>2</sup>) on average, see [Sorting in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms). Yet, it is still worth switching to insertion sort on tiny subarrays in quicksort, see *Cutoff to insertion sort* in [Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X) by Sedgewick & Wayne (p. 296 in the 4th Ed.). They claim that "any value between 5 and 15 is likely to work well in most situations." The resulting algorithm is better than either quicksort or insertion sort alone.